NodeJS child_process spawn not closing even after completion
I am trying to create a ReactNative project with ReactNative CLI. So i am triggering the command in a nodejs script.
We also encounter prompts during the project creation and that has been handled in my code below:
const execWithSpawn = (command, args, options, promptResponses) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const child = spawn(command, args);
        let stdout = '';
        let stderr = '';

        console.log(`Spawning process: ${command} ${args?.join(' ')}`);

        child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            stdout += data.toString();
            console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);

            // Check for prompts and respond if needed
            if (promptResponses) {
                for (const prompt of Object.keys(promptResponses)) {
                    if (data.toString().includes(prompt)) {
                        const response = promptResponses[prompt];
                        child.stdin.write(`${response}\n`);
                        console.log(`Responded to prompt "${prompt}" with: ${response}`);
                        break; // Respond to only the first matching prompt
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            stderr += data.toString();
            console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
        });

        child.on('close', (code) => {
            console.log(`Process closed with code: ${code}`);
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve({ stdout, stderr });
            } else {
                reject(new Error(`Process exited with code ${code}`));
            }
        });

        child.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`Process error: ${err.message}`);
            reject(err);
        });
    });
};

execWithSpawn(
     'npx' ['react-native', 'init', '--version', '70.0.0'],
      undefined, { 'Install cocopods': 'N' }
);

But even after the project is created, the program is not exiting. Also close and exit events are not fired for the child.
NOTE:

This command creates lot of output. So to increase the buffer size, i have configured maxBuffer size but still the behaviour is same.

Also this command exits properly if i run in a shell normally.

Using NodeJS v20.9.0


